# Find $\bigcup_{r\in R}\ \{(x,y): (x-r)^2 + (y+2r)^2 < r^2+1\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, envelope

I have to obtain an union:

$\bigcup_{r\in R}\ \{(x,y): (x-r)^2 + (y+2r)^2 < r^2+1\}$

I know this is a series of circles that is limited by two hyperbolic functions that are symmetrical in relation to $y = -2x$. But how to get an union? I tried putting $y= \frac{1}{2}x$ into the circle's equation to get the intersection points but it works only for $r = 1$. It would require putting $y = \frac{1}{2}x + b, \forall b \in R$ but it doesn't look as a significant simplification. I have also thought of representing an intersection as a translation from $(x, -2x)$ by a vector $\pm\ [\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} \sqrt{r^2+1}, \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}\sqrt{r^2+1}]$ but it hasn't turned out to be usefull aswell. I'm running out of ideas. I'd be really thankful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the envelope of the family of circles given by varying $r$. The union will then be everything "inside" that envelope.

You can find the envelope of the family of curves $f(x,y,r) = 0$ by solving
$$f(x,y,r) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(x,y,r) = 0.$$
In this case (and generally), you should end up by determining the envelope parametrically as functions of $r$. When you eliminate $r$, you should find the equation
$$3x^2+4xy=4,$$
which, as you suggested, is a hyperbola.

Comment: Thanks! But why do I need to differentiate with respect to $r$? And another thing, is it enough to write down that this union equals to the interior between these hyperbolas?

Comment: See the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)). The extra derivative condition is exactly what you need to say that the envelope is *tangent* to the curve in the family where they intersect. Your union will be all the points *between* the two branches of the hyperbola, as I suggested in the first sentence.

Comment: Understood. But when I differentiate $f(x,y,r) = (x-r)^2 + (y+2r)^2 - r^2-1$ with respect to $r$ I get $8r-2x+4y$. There's something wrong.

Comment: No, that's right. Set equal to $0$ and substitute ....

Comment: Right. Then I put it into my $f(x,y)$ and get what you had written. Last question: how could I define this union instead of just writing that it contains everything between these hyperbolas?

Comment: Hint: How about $\{(x,y): ? \le y \le ?\}$?

Comment: I'm sorry. It was late at night.
Thanks for all your help!