# How do you find the area of an egg shape formed from the union of circles whose diameters are horizontal chords of the unit circle?

Tags: geometry, area, envelope

This egg is the union of the red circles, whose diameters are horizontal chords of (the upper half of) the unit circle.

> How do you find its area?

[image]

---

Some background information on this egg is shown below:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  And it isn't a "divine egg."  Its an "egg."

Comment: Please type up your question so people do not have to click through.  Images are not searchable, either.

Comment: Can you clearly state the problem in the body of the question? (Instead of linking to some gifs.) That is, did you mean to ask for the area of the 2-dimensional shape which encompasses the red circles? Then, can you describe the construction of the red circles in the body of the question?

Comment: Yes, that's right, please formulate it correctly

Comment: This question is inherently good! Read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and try re-posting it (after deleting this post).

Comment: If I haven't made a mistake, it should be $\frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{4} R^2  \pi $.

Comment: Thank you, Rahul. You've been very helpful with the formulation of question a. This formula is not correct.  The area of the black circle cannot exceed the area of the red egg...

Comment: @AsseNic: I like this question and have voted to reopen. To improve its chances, I edited it to include the large version of the egg image that you included in a re-post (now closed) and made some minor changes. You should also edit the question to include what you've tried and/or where you got stuck in computing the area yourself. (Have you tried determining the equation of the envelope?) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you are unfamiliar.

Comment: @AsseNic Thank you.

Comment: Blue  Thank you. I don't know how to put an edited theme.

Comment: @AsseNic: There should be an "edit" link ... or  just [click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3503219/edit). Then add whatever thoughts you have on the problem.

Comment: @AsseNic: By the way, using the technique described in the Wikipedia ["Envelope" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)), I have determined that the upper part of the egg is half of an ellipse with minor radius $1$ and major radius $\sqrt{2}$. (A GeoGebra sketch confirms this.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103130/discussion-between-asse-nic-and-blue).

Comment: @AsseNic: (I don't chat, so this is my last comment.) Your "Why does it matter?" edit isn't helpful from a mathematical standpoint. Please give some indication of your level of mathematical sophistication so that people know how to respond to you. Do you want answers that use geometry? trig? calculus? If you aren't very mathematically inclined but simply found this problem interesting, you can say that, too. The community likes to be assured that it isn't being asked to do work that askers can do themselves. (Put any thoughts into the question body, since comments are easily overlooked.)

Comment: Okay, I'll have a lot of new thoughts soon. Unfortunately, I use an electronic translator, so it is not always correct.

Comment: @AsseNic: One last comment. :)  If it would help, you can write in your native language. Someone in the community will almost-certainly be able to help you translate it.

Comment: Ah, I noticed my mistake in my previous comment. I had got the same curve as Blue claims in the comments, but made a silly mistake when multiplying by $2$ before integrating for area.

Comment: The egg of being.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hard work, I'll deal with it now. It took me a long time to translate the text, so I'll send it to you for reflection.

Comment: Friends, I'm gonna step away from the subject a little bit so you can understand me. Perhaps it seems absurd and you'll remove the subject. That's a start. A bit of philosophy, I think at first, there are geometric images. Then there are axioms and formulas that describe them. For example, the image of a circle is primary after a point. The circle is born from a point. The circle, that's what's the basis. The circle is the least of all questions. A circle has a radius, that's the measure. All the points in a circle are equally far from the centre.

Comment: It seems the very possibility of that, divine. Any other figure has more questions. Like an equilateral triangle. In it appears the additional question of this direction. As I have already seen, there is only one way to imagine the attitude to the circle. It's a given "egg in the world's ocean" by

Comment: P.S.  also accidentally found mythical information about the world's egg. This question with the area of the egg, will allow me and all other people to draw conclusions. Primary images.

Comment: But it's not really these conclusions that matter. There's a friendly opportunity. To create a peaceful world. 
Any beginnings on this subject are closed.

Comment: Trying to get this information out since December 21, I'm being removed everywhere. Your mathematical community is the only place for me to be asked questions. I'm very glad.

Comment: I managed to come to this notion of time, with the ability to choose my own attitude to time. This video. 
It illustrates that possibility. 
The most important thing. I hope the mathematical community will confirm that this egg is the supreme image of being. In that case, society will have an interest in my theme: The Triune System of Peace.

Comment: It's possible for all people to be friends. Every human being can be useful. There is no overpopulation. There are many things that we must do together. How many deserted planets there are in the universe, how few of us.

Comment: By developing our inner abilities, we will restore our Earth and populate new planets, creating life there. I see a beautiful future. Thank you all for being here.

Comment: I don't think it's a waste of time if you can see everything clearly. So I've planned a big festival in Montenegro on March 21. I'd be infinitely happy if somebody could help me on this one. 
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cMGEqmRdXQA

Comment: This egg shape is far from being perfect. In particular, it features a discontinuity in the curvature at the equator. This precludes the possibility to create a peaceful world. Consider https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/oeuf/oeuf.shtml

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'm really far away from these formulas. I understand relationships and imagery more clearly. But let's look at some facts.

Comment: Fact one. For the experiment, I went to the store twice for chicken eggs. In the first ten, four out of ten eggs were this form. In the second ten there were only three eggs. 
This experiment showed 1/3 of the similarity. It's easy to check for yourself. You could call this shape an egg and we'd be right.

Comment: Fact two. To represent the decomposition of the red and blue circle so that the equality a/c=c/b can always be performed only in the following way. And only with a circle. This equality, that is, the proportion a/c=c/b explains the simplicity of understanding the Triunity, and also shows the infinitely filled versions of the proportions. Which in the sum describe the given egg.

Comment: The fact is the third. Any measure has this form. So it turns out. It's not my fiction. 
Please try to understand me.

Comment: Asse, you have ruined a good question with your new-age maunderings. A shame.

Comment: TonyK, I'm sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: @TonyK: I suspect that this question was an excuse for propaganda.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, obviously. But it's such a nice picture! Never mind$-$ Asse just promised to fix the question. Balance will be restored.

Answer (score 9):

The chord at ordinate $a$ generates a circle of radius $\sqrt{1-a^2}$,

$$x^2+(y-a)^2=1-a^2.$$

To obtain the envelope, we eliminate $a$, using the derivative on $a$ of this equation,

$$2(a-y)=-2a$$

and we obtain an ellipse of semi-axis $\sqrt 2,1$, of equation:

$$x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}=1.$$

Hence the total area is the average of the ellipse and circle areas

$$\frac{\pi\sqrt2+\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Yves Daoust, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In short it can be shown that the top part of the egg is bounded by half-ellipse with radii $a,b=1,\sqrt2$, and it is given that the bottom part is a half-circle of radius $r=1$. Use the fact that ellipse area is $\pi ab$ and circle area $\pi r^2$, to get that the total area is: $\frac12(\sqrt2+1)\pi$.

Below is how I solved the problem to obtain the above result.

---

Let $R$ be radius of the black circle inside the egg. For the unit circle, set $R=1$.

To recap the problem, I will be solving the problem of the area of the following egg shape: Set defined as union of circles whose diameters are horizontal chords of the upper half of a radius $R$ circle.

We can parameterize the egg by defining the chords as $\overline{AB}$ where:

(I assume you are familiar with [sine and cosine on unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle). We are just scaling it by $R$.)

$$\begin{align}
A&=(R\cos(\alpha),R\sin(\alpha))\\
B&=(R\cos(\pi-\alpha),R\sin(\pi-\alpha))
\end{align}$$

Where the family of chords is now given by all $\overline{AB}$ such that $\alpha\in[0,\pi/2]$.

Each chord defines a circle centered at midpoint of it, with radius $R\cos(\alpha).$

The midpoint (circle center) coordinates are: $(0,R\sin(\alpha))$.

This gives the family of circles which defines the egg:

$$
\bigcup_{\alpha\in[0,\pi/2]} \{x^2+(y-R \sin (\alpha))^2 \le R^2 \cos ^2(\alpha) \}
$$

We are now solving for the envelope of the egg. That is, we need to find the curve bounding the egg, so we can integrate for the area. Notice that due to symmetry and periodic functions, we can equivalently search for the envelope given by all chords and let $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, and then take the part of it above $x$-axis.

A similar problem has already been solved: "[Find $\bigcup_{r\in R}\ \{(x,y): (x-r)^2 + (y+2r)^2 < r^2+1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3445791/318073)".

The goal is to solve for $\alpha$ from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}(x,y,\alpha)=0$ and substitute it back into $f(x,y,\alpha)=0$.

That is, we find the derivative of $f(x,y,\alpha)=0$ in respect to $\alpha$ :

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y,\alpha)&=x^2+(y-R \sin (\alpha))^2-R^2 \cos ^2(\alpha)\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}(x,y,\alpha) &= 2 R \cos (\alpha) (2 R \sin (\alpha)-y)
\end{align}$$

Solving $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}(x,y,\alpha)=0$, notice that $2R\cos(\alpha)$ is the length of the chord (twice the radius of initial circle) and hence we can assume it is positive. This means it must be $(2 R \sin (\alpha)-y)=0$, from which we obtain $\alpha=\arcsin(\frac{y}{2R})$.

Substituting $\alpha$ into $f(x,y,\alpha)=0$ and after simplifying, we get:

$$\begin{align}
x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}&=R^2\\
\frac{x^2}{R^2}+\frac{y^2}{(\sqrt2 R)^2}&=1
\end{align}$$

Which is an ellipse. I have sketched this and made [a Geogebra construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSvuR.png) to triple-check my calculation so far. (I've been using Mathematica to double-check the derivation and substitution).

We need to integrate the area above $x$-axis and below the upper part of the obtained envelope:

$$
y=\sqrt{2(R^2-x^2)}
$$

To get the upper part of the egg. The area below the $x$-axis is simply half a circle and given by $ \frac12 R^2\pi$.

In total we have:

$$
\text{Area(Egg)}=\left(\int_{-R}^R dx\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2(R^2-x^2)}}dy\right) + \frac12 R^2\pi
$$

This integral can be done by substituting in the polar coordinates.

But you can also avoid integration by accepting that the area of the ellipse is $\pi ab$. We have $a=R, b=\sqrt2R$, and we are after half of an ellipse, so we have: $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R^2\pi$. That is:

$$
\text{Area(Egg)}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R^2\pi + \frac12 R^2\pi
$$

By summing half the area of the ellipse for upper part, and half the area of circle for bottom part.

Finally, we have:

> $$
> \text{Area(Egg)}=\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2} R^2  \pi 
> $$

Plug in $R=1$ to obtain the case when the black circle is the unit circle.

Comment: Why do you carry that $R$ all along ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I initially started solving the problem before it was edited and specified that $R=1$ (that we are working with a unit circle).

Comment: I understand. (For similar problems I would often start with WLOG $R=1$.)

Comment: Thank you. Great, that sounds like the truth.  Maybe even the truth.

Comment: Vipir, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We take chord mid-point height $h$ as parameter.
$$(x-0)^2+(y-h)^2=(\sqrt{R^2-h^2})^2; x^2+y^2-2yh+2h^2 = R^2\tag1 $$
To find envelope we take partial derivative w.r.t.$ h$
$$-2y+4h=0\rightarrow y=2h \tag2$$
and eliminating $h$ between them
$$ x^2 + y^2/2=R^2 \tag3$$
which is an ellipse. The two parts of egg (half-ellipse,circle) have area
$$\frac12 \pi R \sqrt2R+\,\frac12 \pi R^2 \tag4$$

Parametric plot of (1) in *Mathematica* showing egg shape:

```
R = 1; ParametricPlot[{Sqrt[R^2 - h^2] Cos[t], 
  Sqrt[R^2 - h^2] Sin[t] + h}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {h, 0, R}, 
 Mesh -> {20, 9}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {Magenta, Thick}]
```

[image]

Comment: Narasimham,  thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Only the essential  parameter  h and its variation are indicated in answer for clarity.